# How can I sort a table in a many to many relationship by a pivot table column?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to sort a table of teachers by the school they belong to. The name of the school is a column in the pivot table.

I have a table of teachers, a table of schools and a pivot table. The teacher's table has ID, lastname, firstname. The schools' table has ID, school_name. The pivot table ('teacher_school') has ID, school_ID, teacher_ID. I know how to sort the teachers' table by teachers' lastname but no idea how to sort teachers by its school name.

1.My teacher model:

```
 class Teacher extends Model
 {
 public $table = "teachers";
 public $primaryKey = "ID";
 public $timestamps = false;
 public $guarded = [];

 public function schools() {
 return $this->belongsToMany("App\School", "teacher_school", 
 "teacher_ID", "school_ID");
 }
 }
```

2. My school model:

```
    class School extends Model
    {
    public $table = "schools";
    public $primaryKey = "ID";
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $guarded = [];

    public function teachers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Teacher", "teacher_school", "school_ID", "teacher_ID");
    }
    }
```

3. My current teachers' controller (which sorts teachers by "ID", not by their school name):

```
    public function listBySchool(Request $req) {
    $teachers = Teacher::orderBy('ID')->paginate(200);
    return view("listTeachersBySchool", compact("teachers"));
    }
```

4. My view:

```
    @foreach ($teachers as $teacher)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$teacher["ID"]}}</td>
    <td>{{$teacher["lastname"]}}</td>
    <td>{{$teacher["firstname"]}}</td>
    <td>
    @foreach ($teacher->schools as $school)
    {{$school["school_name"]}}
    @endforeach
    </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Please help me to make my view display teachers ordered by their school names. ¡Thanks a ton!

Comment: try this in your controller: `Teacher::with('schools')->orderBy('pivot_school_ID')->paginate(200):`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. There is something that I don't understand well when you say "The name of the school is a column in the pivot table" but then you say "The pivot table ('teacher_school') has ID, school_ID, teacher_ID" and "The schools' table has ID, school_name ". So, you want to sort it by the name of the school, which is in the schools table (and not in the pivot table).

Comment: I tried  `$teachers = Teacher::with('schools')->orderBy('school_I')->paginate(200)` and I got this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'school_ID' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `teachers` order by `school_ID` asc limit 200 offset 0)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I want to sort teachers by school ID but want the ordered list to show the name of the school. I think would be better to try a different approach listing the schools in alfabetical order showing the teachers of each school. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I add `->withPivot()`in both models, I get an error saying `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::withPivot(), 0 passed in /Applications/Composer/hadeci2/app/Teacher.php on line 18 and exactly 1 expected`

Comment: Done!! Thanks everyone. Finally I took the Schools approach. In my Schools controller: `public function listBySchool() {
      $sortedSchools = School::with('teachers')->orderBy("school_name")->paginate(200);
      return view("listTeachersBySchool", compact("sortedSchools"));
    }` In my view: `@foreach ($school->teachers as $teacher)
        {{$teacher["last_name"]}}
      @endforeach` Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to sort the teachers by the school name from schools table. Because the pivot table mentioned above doesn't have the school name.

I recommend using a multiple-join query to achieve what you want.

```
Teacher::select('teachers.*')
    ->join('teacher_school', 'teachers.id', '=', 'teacher_school.teacher_id')
    ->join('schools', 'teacher_school.school_id', '=', 'schools.id')
    ->orderBy('schools.school_name')
    ->distinct();
```